# Regex to parse CSS selector

Tags: python, regex, css-selectors

I want to parse this CSS Selector (and others of a similar form):
`div.class1#myid.class2[key=value]`

and have it match ".class1" and ".class2" but I can't figure out what regex to use..

example: http://www.rubular.com/r/3dxpzyJLeK

In an ideal world, I'd also want to extract the:

- type (i.e. div)
- class (i.e. a list of classes)
- id (i.e myid)
- key (i.e. key)
- operator (i.e. =)
- value (i.e. value)

but I can't get the basics going!

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you want all that info, you're better off using something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).  It also looks like there are a couple libraries doing this already -- http://cthedot.de/cssutils/ and http://code.google.com/p/css-py/ -- although it's not clear how complete they are.

Comment: In theory, there could be more than one `[key=value]`, either using separate lists for key and value, or using an attribute list that contains key-value pairs. And "tag" might be more appropriate than "type".

Comment: Plus, there are more variations for an attribute, with and without quotes for the attribute values: `[type]`, `[type^=value]`, `[type$=value]`, etc, if that matters, such that it may be necessary to store the attribute operator as well.

Comment: Study the grammar: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html and take a look at existing regex-for-CSS-selectors questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+css-selectors

Comment: By the way, the "key", "operator" and "value" shouldn't be parsed separately - parse them together as an attribute selector, and capture the operator/value optionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all very much for your suggestions and help.  I tied it all together into the following two Regex Patterns:

This one parses the CSS selector string (e.g. div#myid.myclass[attr=1,fred=3])  http://www.rubular.com/r/2L0N5iWPEJ

```
cssSelector = re.compile(r'^(?P<type>[\*|\w|\-]+)?(?P<id>#[\w|\-]+)?(?P<classes>\.[\w|\-|\.]+)*(?P<data>\[.+\])*$')

>>> cssSelector.match("table#john.test.test2[hello]").groups()
('table', '#john', '.test.test2', '[hello]')
>>> cssSelector.match("table").groups()
('table', None, None, None)
>>> cssSelector.match("table#john").groups()
('table', '#john', None, None)
>>> cssSelector.match("table.test.test2[hello]").groups()
('table', None, '.test.test2', '[hello]')
>>> cssSelector.match("table#john.test.test2").groups()
('table', '#john', '.test.test2', None)
>>> cssSelector.match("*#john.test.test2[hello]").groups()
('*', '#john', '.test.test2', '[hello]')
>>> cssSelector.match("*").groups()
('*', None, None, None)
```

And this one does the attributes (e.g. [link,key~=value]) http://www.rubular.com/r/2L0N5iWPEJ:

```
attribSelector = re.compile(r'(?P<word>\w+)\s*(?P<operator>[^\w\,]{0,2})\s*(?P<value>\w+)?\s*[\,|\]]')

>>> a = attribSelector.findall("[link, ds9 != test, bsdfsdf]")
>>> for x in a: print x
('link', '', '')
('ds9', '!=', 'test')
('bsdfsdf', '', '')
```

A couple of things to note:
1) This parses attributes using comma delimitation (since I am not using strict CSS).
2) This requires patterns take the format: tag, id, classes, attributes

The first regex does tokens, so the whitespace and '>' separated parts of a selector string.  This is because I wanted to use it to check against my own object graph :)

Thanks again!

Comment: This is really helpfull, is it easy to add psuedo part? Like `:first-child`? It would really help me out.

Comment: @John I want to same for php. would you please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you nees something like that.

```
(?P<tag>[a-zA-Z]+)?(\.(?P<class>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?)?(#(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_-])?)?\W*\{((?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?)=(?P<value>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?))*\}
```

Sorry if it not works, I have not test it

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't try to do this with a single regexp. Regular expressions are notoriously difficult to read and debug so when you get done with the first 80% of this task and go back to try to fix a bug, the code is going to be a nightmare.

Instead, try writing functions or even a class that will allow you to do the things you want to do. Then you can use a relatively simple regexp for each specific task and use a much more intuitive syntax in your implementations.

```
class css_parser:

  def __init__(self):
    self.class_regexp = re.compile('\.[\w\-]*') # This is insufficient, but it's a start...

  def get_class(self, str):
    m = self.class_regexp.match(str)
    return m.group(0)
```

You'll want to consult [The W3C CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) particularly section 4.